Kafka in docker: No connection to node with id 1
I am trying to send data to local Kafka infrastructure
My infrastructure:
version: "3.8"
    
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
        environment:
            - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

    kafka:
        image: bitnami/kafka:latest
        ports:
            - 9092:9092
            - 9093:9093
        environment:
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
            - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
            - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
            - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
            - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
            - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT
            - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092
            - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092
            - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper

The code to send some data to Kafka:
import asyncio

from aiokafka import AIOKafkaProducer


async def send_to_kafka():
    producer = AIOKafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
        enable_idempotence=True)
    await producer.start()
    try:
        await producer.send_and_wait("my_topic", b"Super message")
    finally:
        await producer.stop()

asyncio.run(send_to_kafka())

I have an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_producer.py", line 16, in <module>
    asyncio.run(send_to_kafka())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.20/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.20/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "tests/test_producer.py", line 10, in send_to_kafka
    await producer.start()
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/51_fetcher_new/Fetcher-Service/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiokafka/producer/producer.py", line 352, in start
    await self.client.bootstrap()
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/51_fetcher_new/Fetcher-Service/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 269, in bootstrap
    self._api_version = await self.check_version()
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/51_fetcher_new/Fetcher-Service/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 564, in check_version
    raise KafkaConnectionError(f"No connection to node with id {node_id}")
aiokafka.errors.KafkaConnectionError: KafkaConnectionError: No connection to node with id 1
Unclosed AIOKafkaProducer

Also was trying to replace bootstrap server with
bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092',

But still have error:
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/51_fetcher_new/Fetcher-Service/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 265, in bootstrap
    raise KafkaConnectionError(f"Unable to bootstrap from {self.hosts}")
aiokafka.errors.KafkaConnectionError: KafkaConnectionError: Unable to bootstrap from [('kafka', 9092, <AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC: 0>)]
Unclosed AIOKafkaProducer


1} Kafka no longer needs Zookeeper. 2) Your advertised listeners config is incorrect. Where are you copying from? Do you understand what all the environment variables do? Your compose file only works without modification when the Python app is also in a container in the same compose file

How can I modify advertised listeners config? I was using https://hub.mos.ru/viktor.shv1995/fastapi-kafka-client/-/tree/main/ but I have to use  fastapi app inside docker compose

@OneCricketeer I am stuck don't understand how should I change hosts in docker-compose.yaml

My other answer explains exactly what you need. Or why can't you just dockerize your Python code then? If you don't want to do that, then don't use a kafka container - https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

@OneCricketeer looks like i configured hosts correctly but still have errors. Could you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79229946/failed-to-create-new-kafkaadminclient-in-docker ?
