Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient in Docker
I want to create kafka-topic in docker container and send message from my python code outside docker container to this topic
My actions
1 Read this article https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/
2 Created kafka infrastructure in docker
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

# This has three listeners you can experiment with. 
# BOB for internal traffic on the Docker network
# FRED for traffic from the Docker-host machine (`localhost`)
# ALICE for traffic from outside, reaching the Docker host on the DNS name `never-gonna-give-you-up`
# Use 
  kafka0:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.2.1"
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29094:29094'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://kafka0:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://kafka0:29094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://never-gonna-give-you-up:29094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_BOB:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_ALICE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_BOB
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100

3 Created python script to send messages to the topic
import asyncio

from aiokafka import AIOKafkaProducer


async def send_to_kafka():
    producer = AIOKafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
        enable_idempotence=True)
    await producer.start()
    try:
        await producer.send_and_wait("my-topic-1", b"Super message")
    finally:
        await producer.stop()

asyncio.run(send_to_kafka())

I have an error:
Topic my-topic-1 not found in cluster metadata

I was trying to create a topic in docker-container
docker exec -ti  fetcher-service-kafka0-1 bash
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka0:29092 --create --if-not-exists --topic my-topic-1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1


[2024-11-27 12:11:11,237] WARN Couldn't resolve server kafka0:29092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  | Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:386)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:55)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService$.createAdminClient(TopicCommand.scala:150)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:154)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:55)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:90)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:49)
fetcher-service-init-kafka-1  |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:346)

How to fix the errors?

Why is your service named  kafka0?

Is it a problem? I just want to be sure that is't my custom name.
fetcher-service-kafka0-1 --- it's a kafka docker container

It is actually, add hostname: kafka to kafka0 service
definition. This will solve Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 error
but there will be others.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk replaced kafka with kafka0, but it didn't help. See updated question

The listeners (which are different from advertised listeners) should not list any hostname at all... Please copy a different example and use the official apache kafka docker image. https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/docker/examples#examples
